# How can I group by the individual elements of a list of elements in Scala

Tags: scala

Forgive me if I'm not naming things by their actual name, I've just started to learn Scala. I've been looking around for a while, but can not find a clear answer to my question.

Suppose I have a list of objects, each object has two fields: `x: Int` and `l: List[String]`, where the Strings, in my case, represent categories.

The `l` lists can be of arbitrary length, so an object can belong to multiple categories. Furthermore, various objects can belong to the same category. My goal is to group the objects by the individual categories, where the categories are the keys. This means that if an object is linked to say "N" categories, it will occur in "N" of the key-value pairs.

So far I managed to groupBy the lists of categories through:
`objectList.groupBy(x => x.l)`
However, this obviously groups the objects by list of categories rather than by categories.

I'm trying to do this with immutable collections avoiding loops etc.

If anyone has some ideas that would be much appreciated!
Thanks

EDIT:
By request the actual case class and what I am trying.
`case class Car(make: String, model: String, fuelCapacity: Option[Int], category:Option[List[String]])`
Once again, a car can belong to multiple categories. Let's say `List("SUV", "offroad", "family")`.

I want to group by `category` elements rather than by the whole list of categories, and have the `fuelCapacity` as the values, in order to be able to extract average `fuelCapacity` per category amongst other metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your EDIT as a guide.

```
case class Car( make: String
              , model: String
              , fuelCapacity: Option[Int]
              , category:Option[List[String]] )

val cars: List[Car] = ???

//all currently known category strings
val cats: Set[String] = cars.flatMap(_.category).flatten.toSet

//category -> list of cars in this category
val catMap: Map[String,List[Car]] =
  cats.map(cat => (cat, cars.filter(_.category.contains(cat)))).toMap

//category -> average fuel capacity for cars in this category 
val fcAvg: Map[String,Double] =
  catMap.map{case (cat, cars) =>
    val fcaps: List[Int] = cars.flatMap(_.fuelCapacity)
    if (fcaps.lengthIs < 1) (cat, -1d)
    else (cat, fcaps.sum.toDouble / fcaps.length)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following?

```scala
objectList // Seq[YourType]
  .flatMap(o => o.l.map(c => c -> o)) // Seq[(String, YourType)]
  .groupBy { case (c,_) => c } // Map[String,Seq[(String,YourType)]]
  .mapValues { items => c -> items.map { case (_, o) => o } } // Map[String, Seq[YourType]]
```

*(Deliberately "heavy" to help you understand the idea behind it)*

EDIT, or as of Scala 2.13 thanks to `groupMap`:

```scala
objectList // Seq[YourType]
  .flatMap(o => o.l.map(c => c -> o)) // Seq[(String, YourType)]
  .groupMap { case (c,_) => c } { case (_, o) => o } // Map[String,Seq[YourType]]
```

Comment: So the flatMap returns a sequence of tuples```Seq[(String, YourType)]```.  Should I interpret this in the way that every tuple contains one category and one object? So say that an object belongs to N categories, the object maps to N separate tuples? And then the groupBy groups all the tuples which have the same category string at ```tuple._1```?

Comment: Because the flatMap code you provided does not seem to give this result. The result I get from this is: ```List[(List[String], YourType)]```. My understanding of flatmap was that this would flatten all the inner lists? How come categories are still in a list inside the tuple?

Comment: You should probably add the actual case class you use in your original post or open a new one with the code you tried and the issues you have with it. Hard to help without seeing that.

Comment: You're right, just added that. Tried to keep it general but this is probably more clear.

Comment: Okay, so the diff with what I was expecting is you got an `Option[List]`. Replace the first `flatMao` with `o.l.getOrElse(Seq())` instead of `o.l`.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, you just need to split each individual element in the list before the `group` so try with something like this:

```scala
// I used a Set instead of a List,
// since I don't think the order of categories matters
// as well I would think having two times the same category doesn't make sense.
final case class MyObject(x: Int, categories: Set[String] = Set.empty) {
  def addCategory(category: String): MyObject =
    this.copy(categories = this.categories + category)
}

def groupByCategories(data: List[MyObject]): Map[String, List[Int]] =
  data
    .flatMap(o => o.categories.map(c => c -> o.x))
    .groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
```